# .htaccess redirect for .pdf/.doc file in the root folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pdf, redirect

I am trying to create a rewrite rule similar to the one below

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*+/.pdf)$ /site-content/import/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any url request similar to

```
http://hostname/filename.pdf
```

Should redirect to

```
http://hostname/site-content/import/uploads/filename.pdf
```

But it should not redirect if the request file name is inside a sub folder and also it should not redirect the urls other than .pdf or .doc files

```
http://hostname/sub-page/filename.pdf
http://hostname/sub-page/sub/filename.pdf
http://hostname/sub-page
http://hostname/image.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.pdf)$ /site-content/import/uploads/$1 [R,L]
```

or this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^/.]+\.pdf)$ /site-content/import/uploads/$1
```

Clear your browser caches before testing this redirect.

EDIT:

The examples above redirect .pdf files only, to redirect both .pdf and .doc ,you can use this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.(pdf|doc)$ /site-content/import/uploads%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Does it also matches `/filename.pdf`? Also it matches only `.pdf` files.

Answer (score 2):

Try regex `^/[^/]+\.(pdf|doc)$`. Will match first `/`, any character that is not `/` and ends with `.pdf` or `.doc`.

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/6lmvAg/1)

---

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+\.(?:pdf|doc))$ /site-content/import/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Then how is the complete rewrite rule should be looks like?

Comment: I have checked the same here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/
but there is something went wrong.

Comment: This wont work on htaccess context as it contains a leading slash.

Comment: I have used this 

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.(?:pdf|doc))$ /site-content/import/uploads/$1 [R,L]

and seems working here http://htaccess.mwl.be/